# How to make the character jump but only to a certain height and then come back down to ground level?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am currently trying to work on a small project for my programming module and I am still very much a beginner since it's just the first semester. I want to make my character jump when I press the Up-arrow key but only to a certain height and then come back down, I can't figure out how to do this, for now when I press the arrow key, the character keeps going up if I keep holding it down and stops otherwise in mid-air. this is the link for my code in the online editor since I can't post all the code down here [GP 3A](https://editor.p5js.org/cormacang70/sketches/-r8R9iB6i). The part below is where I am having trouble.

```
    if (isLeft == true)
    {
        gameChar_x -= 5
    }
    if (isRight == true)
    {
        gameChar_x += 5
    }
    if (isJumping == true)
    {
        gameChar_y -= 5
    }
    // if (gameChar_y == gameChar_y - 5)
    // {
    //  gameChar_y += 5
    // }
    // if (isPlummeting == true)
    // {
    //  gameChar_y += 10
    // }

}


function keyPressed()
{
    // if statements to control the animation of the character when
    // keys are pressed.

    //open up the console to see how these work
    // console.log("keyPressed: " + key);
    // console.log("keyPressed: " + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == 37)
    {
        isLeft = true
    }
    else if (keyCode == 39)
    {
        isRight = true
    }
    else if (keyCode == 38)
    {
        isJumping = true
    }
}

function keyReleased()
{
    // if statements to control the animation of the character when
    // keys are released.

    // console.log("keyReleased: " + key);
    // console.log("keyReleased: " + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == 37)
    {
        isLeft = false
    }
    else if (keyCode == 39)
    {
        isRight = false
    }
    else if (keyCode == 38)
    {
        isJumping = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jumping = false;
var gravity = 1;

var rectangle = {
    x: 20,
    y: 0, 
    vx: 10, // X velocity
    vy: 5, // Y velocity  velocity = acceleration
  
    size: 80
};

var ground = {
    x: 0,
    y: 600-rectangle.size,
    width: 600
};



function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
}





function draw () {
    background('#000000');
    
    // The Rectangle
    fill('red');
    rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.size);
    
    // Physics
    rectangle.y += rectangle.vy; // contantly add y velocity
    rectangle.vy += gravity; // constantly add gravity to Y           
    // Ground check
    if (rectangle.y > ground.y - 0 && rectangle.x <= ground.width) {
        rectangle.y = ground.y - 0;
        rectangle.vy = 0;       
        jumping = false;    
            } 
        
  // Right 
if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    rectangle.x += rectangle.vx;
    }
// Left
if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    rectangle.x -= rectangle.vx;
    }

  
  
}




// THE JUMP
function keyPressed() {
    if (jumping === false && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        rectangle.vy -= 10;
        jumping = true;
        console.log(jumping); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).